# Artisan Laravel não instalado

Tags: php, laravel, artisan

Instalei o laravel com composer tudo funcionando ... Utilizo comandos como `laravel new projeto`, porém se uso um comando como `php artisan list` ele informa que o comando artisan não é reconhecido... Como posso "instalar o artisan"?
Obs :

- Uso Mac
- Uso MAMP

Comment: Quando tento chamar esse comando, você estava na pasta do projeto no terminal?

Comment: @rray era isto mesmo... não sabia... por favor escreva isso em uma resposta para oder dar como aceita.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Para utiliza os comandos do artisan é necessário estar na pasta do projeto no terminal.

Comment: @augustoFurlan, pode editar se tiver mais alguma coisa para complementar.

Answer (score 0):

dentro da pasta do projeto você deve dar composer install para instalar as dependências do projeto